# Mongodb history of commands in the .dbshell file

Tags: mongodb

mongo maintains a history of commands in the .dbshell file.
Where in windows folder can we see this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the user's home directory. `<root>\Users\<username>`

E.g. `C:\Users\Jack`